# yii2 pretty url has broken search in GridView

Tags: php, search, yii2

I have a link without `urlManager` while searching in `GridView`:

```
project/backend/web/index.php?CountrySearch%5Bid%5D=1&CountrySearch%5Bname%5D=&r=country%2Findex
```

When I enable `urlManager` I can't search in `GridView`, I think it is because I have to change rules.

Now my url looks like this: `project/country/index`
Could someone help me with rules, so search in `GridView` could work?

Comment: Can you add the whole view and the action please?

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of your `.htaccess` file? Could be an issue with your url rewriting.

Answer (score -1):

Does your configuration like the following LOCs?

```
'urlManager' => [ 
    'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager', 
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
    'showScriptName' => false,  
],
```